# disabling a link inside a table column if checkbox is unchecked in the same row

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

i want to disable these two buttons if my checkbox from below is unchecked

```
    <td><a href="manage-bookings.php?aeid=<?php echo htmlentities($result- 
    >id);?>" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to Confirm this 
    booking?')"> Confirm</a> /

    <a href="manage-bookings.php?eid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);? 
    >" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to Cancel this 
    Request?')"> Cancel</a>
    </td>
```

//checkbox

```
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="requirements"></td>
```

Comment: This should be done by Javascript, not PHP. Read about jQuery and dom events to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener for the `change` event on the checkbox which toggles a `.disabled` class on the links parent `td` which ignores pointer events and greys them out.

Here's an example:

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.link-container')

document
  .querySelector('#checkbox')
  .addEventListener('change', e => {
    containers.forEach(container => {
      container.classList.toggle('disabled')
    })
  })
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px;
}

td.disabled a {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="link-container">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">Visit Google</a>
    </td>
     <td class="link-container">
      <a href="https://www.microsoft.com">Visit Microsoft</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery for this problem

Set id for the checkbox like this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="requirements" id="requirements" /></td>
```

then add a listener in jquery to check if user has check the checkbox like this:

```
$("#requirements").on('click', function(){
  if($(this). prop("checked") == true){
   alert("Checkbox is checked." );
   link here is enabled

  }
  else if($(this). prop("checked") == false){
   alert("Checkbox is unchecked." );
   link here is disabled
  }
});
```